# Importing and Using a Swift SnapshotTesting Framework with Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, pointfree

I'm having issues running xcTests after importing the SnapshotTesting framework available from 
 -> https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing#installation

The build succeeds but the test fails

I always get a "Symbol not found: " saying it expected to find it in ....Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

e.g.

> 2018-12-11 17:39:48.799290+1100 Life[38438:3178136] Failed to load
>   test bundle from
>   file:///Users/garrypugh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Life-cowbtmytjcqvmqgvgonauprqpbpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Life.app/PlugIns/LifeTests.xctest/:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588
>   "dlopen(/Users/garrypugh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Life-cowbtmytjcqvmqgvgonauprqpbpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Life.app/PlugIns/LifeTests.xctest/LifeTests,
>   265): Symbol not found: _$SSS8UTF8ViewVs8SequencesWP   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/garrypugh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Life-cowbtmytjcqvmqgvgonauprqpbpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Life.app/PlugIns/LifeTests.xctest/Frameworks/SnapshotTesting.framework/SnapshotTesting
>   Expected in:
>   /Users/garrypugh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA4AAED2-B310-4590-BCEB-AF28312A0B35/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A7A23001-D0C6-47C9-ADED-F31A1136A0BB/Life.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

I have followed the Carthage Instructions here ->

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos

and here ->

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework

And have successfully (seemingly) downloaded and built the frameworks

1. Set up Cartfile
2. Run carthage update - which built the 3 frameworks (Mac, iOS, tvOS) 
   i.e. SnapshotTesting.framework and their related SnapshotTesting.framework .dSYM files

Then when attempting to include this in the Testing Target of my iOS App I followed the following steps

1. Dragged the iOS SnapshotTesting.framework file to the Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries Section
2. Added a /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks with

   Input Files     $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/SnapshotTesting.framework

   Output Files  $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/SnapshotTesting.framework
3. I have ensured that my Runpath Search Paths  (within Build Settings tab) has -> @loader_path/Frameworks

I am running Xcode 10.1

I'm not sure if this is a Issue with

1. Carthage setup
2. The SnapshotTesting framework
3. My build settings in Xcode
4. Or a restriction with dynamic verses static frameworks?

I have tried a few variations on locations of the Input / Output files,  running the the Runscript before and after the Link Binary Section

Does anyone recognise this issue, Is there some other build settings that need to change enable this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

1. First, Don't drag and drop the carthage generated framework to the Test Target / Build Phases (tab) Link Binary With Libraries (section). Instead use the + button and "Add Other" navigating to the .../Carthage/Build/iOS and choose the framework file in question.
   Delete the .framework file if you have previously dragged it (and it copied it into the directory)
2. Second, Add a New Copy Files section in the Build Phases Tab (Last step) with a Destination of Frameworks. Again use the + button to select the SnapshotTesting.framework within Carthage/Build/iOS
   Remove the Run Script Phase - With - "/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks" if you have previously added it.

Thanks to the guys at www.pointfree.co

[Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR3kB.png)

3. And a final Gotcha - After doing this I was receiving the build error "Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler:" within the xcTest test case where I attempted to import SnapshotTesting.
   This issue was caused by the fact that I was running Xcode 10.1 - But within Xcode Preferences / Locations Tab the Command Line Tools dropdown had Xcode 10.0 selected - Which I suspect meant that when Carthage was generating the framework modules it was using the older version resulting in a Swift version mismatch?

[Command Line Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpE6r.png)